# On XP, transfer files to external 2TB solid state drive, error message that 'insufficient space available'

Tags: windows-xp

On XP, transfer 75GB file to external 2TB solid state drive, error message that 'insufficient space available' when over 1TB left. How to achieve this transfer?

Comment: 75GB single file or multiple files? Can you be more clear about that?

Comment: Please modify the title. It says you're trying to transfer to a 2GB solid state drive which if you were trying to transfer 75GB, would have insufficient space.

Comment: @FiascoLabs it won't transfer if it formatted fat32....

Comment: 2TB SSD, who can afford that?...http://www.myce.com/news/foremay-ships-worlds-largest-2tb-ssd-32332/

Answer (score 3):

If it is formatted as FAT (or FAT32) and it has 512byte sectors then the maximum filesize possible is 4GB. Try formatting as NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Best option for your 2TB hard disk is to format it into a Ntfs, then try again, it should work.